# How can I add linebreaks in the generated html

Tags: derbyjs

I'm starting from the minimal derby application created by `derby new first-project`. Thereby, the body of the produced html is written in a single line. How can I switch that behavior off to get a pretty printed html to be able to track down bugs like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is indeed single-line html, then your answer is x-no-minify: http://derbyjs.com/#whitespace_and_html_conformance.

However, I think your problem is just that the derby starter-project generator, and the examples, are way out of date. Use the [derby-boilerplate project](https://github.com/codeparty/derby/wiki/Using-Derby-%22Edge%22)

Comment: Is there a possibility to globally enable `x-no-minify`?

Comment: not that i know of, but you shouldn't need it for most things right? Isn't it a fringe case where minification breaks stuff?

Comment: Maybe my whole development setting is strange. I'd like to debug my JavaScript code in my browser. Maybe I should start developing without derby and only plugin derby at very end of the development.